# How to implement Delayed Chained Payments in PayPal on android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Can anyone tell me how to implement PayPal's Delayed Chained Payments in android app.
I am using last version sdk for android PayPal_MPL_1.5.5.44_Android-Developer-Package.
I did not found any mentions to the Delayed Payments in this sdk.
Regarding the Adaptive Payment documentation we should specify actionType="PAY_PRIMARY" for this purpose. But I did not found such ability.

I have already implemented chained payment in the app, but currently money sending immediately from the primary recipient to the secondary recipient w/o any delay.

Is it possible to implement such feature using sdk for android?

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from support.

> No, it is not possible to submit a delayed chained payment using the
>   Android SDK package because there is no method that allows you to do
>   it. The confirmation comes in the form of there not being any method
>   in the SDK to set the payment type to "PAY_PRIMARY", and also no
>   method to execute the second leg of a chain